# Issue with "for" and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to have the user input delivery information and use the for loop. I keep getting an IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I want it to print and have the user input each item then after ask if info is correct and if not return them. However, I cannot get to for statement correct after trying multiple ways. Thank you.

```
address = []
address_info = ('Name:', 'Address:', 'City:', 'State', 'Zip Code')

print('***DELIVERY METHOD***')
print('Please enter the info below from customer...')
for x in address_info:
    address[x] = input(address_info[x])
    x += 1
```

Comment: You can't assign to indices that don't exist. You need to *`append()`* to add more elements, or start your input list with at least `len(address_info)` elements.

Comment: Change the `address = []` to `address = {}` and on the for loop change `input(address_info[x])` to `input(x)` and remove the line `x += 1`

Comment: And remove the `x += 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using append-logic instead of using indexing.

```
address = []
address_info = ('Name:', 'Address:', 'City:', 'State', 'Zip Code')

print('***DELIVERY METHOD***')
print('Please enter the info below from customer...')

for info in address_info:     # these are the values not indicies
    user_input = input(info)
    address.append(user_input)
```

There were to issues in your original code.  First, the for-loop will loop over the values from *address_info* rather than the indicies.  Second, the result list needs to be grown by appends; you can't make an indexed assignment until the list already has some value at the the position that can be replaced.

Comment: Thank you! That worked out well... I figured I was overthinking the code again...

Comment: @MatthewPhaneuf Glad to have helped.  I just gave you an upvote because I think this was a good question that has an interesting answer.